# CMD output textfile how to ensure it is done

Tags: cmd, uipath, rpa

I need to make sure that my output textfile is finished after running my scrcpy program with cmd and I have tried to use echo "output finished" but this is not written to the output file until the program is closed.

Using UiPath RPA I am running a batch file that has the following command:
@ECHO OFF
cd \program files\scrcpy-win64

(scrcpy -m 640 -b 2M

echo "output finished"

) > C:\Path\CMDoutput.txt

When scrcpy is executed the CMDoutput.txt is being created and I am using a copy file and then Read textfile activity to get the string output from CMDoutput.txt. BUT I am only getting part of the string as the CMDoutput.txt is still being written and I do not know how long it takes before it is finalized. So how do I know when all the output is written to CMDoutput.txt? Can I somehow insert a "output finished" thereby checking my string and knowing that the whole string is taken?

I also tried using PowerShell invoke activity in UiPath but when the scrcpy program launched the RPA stops untill I close scrcpy. If I could make the RPA continue while still running scrcpy this could maybe be an alternative solution.